# Sort Array Based on Another Array's Sorting

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have two arrays:

```js
arr1 = [4,2,3,5,1]
arr2 = ['a','b','c','d','e']
```

And if I apply an sorting algorithm to arr1, (e.g. by smaller number) it should update the indexes in the same way on arr2 (if arr1's 4, before in index 0 gets moved to index 3, arr2's value in index 0 gets moved to index 3).
ex.

```js
arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
arr2 = ['e','b','c','a','d']
```

I've tried working with the JS sort function to no avail. Because the numbers in the arrays may be duplicates, `indexOf()` doesn't work. I don't feel I need to implement my own sorting algorithm because I really feel like an elegant way is possible here.

Comment: Don't use separate arrays. Combine the two arrays into a single array of pairs, and sort that by the first element.

Comment: This looks like bad practice to me since the sort would depend on both arrays being the same length. Are you able to combine them into a single array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An one-liner (combine the arrays, sort and update the arrays with `Array::forEach()`:

```js
let arr1 = [4,2,3,5,1];
let arr2 = ['a','b','c','d','e'];

arr1.map((item, i) => [item, arr2[i]]).sort(([a],[b]) => a - b).forEach((item, i) => (arr1[i] = item[0], arr2[i] = item[1]));

console.log(...arr1);
console.log(...arr2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using an extra array should work for you something like this:

```js
const arr3 = arr1.map((elem,index) => { return [arr1[index], arr2[index]] }).sort((a,b) => a[0] - b[0]); //b-a for desc

arr1 = arr3.map((elem,index) => { return arr3[index][0] });
arr2 = arr3.map((elem,index) => { return arr3[index][1] });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by combining Array 1 and Array 2 to one single array and then sorting the combined array by the values of array one.

Refer the code below :

```js
function customSort(arr1, arr2) {
  // Combine arr1 and arr2 into an array of objects
  const combinedArray = arr1.map((value, index) => ({ value, arr2Value: arr2[index] }));

  // Sort the combined array based on the values in arr1
  combinedArray.sort((a, b) => a.value - b.value);

  // Update arr1 and arr2 based on the sorted order
  for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    arr1[i] = combinedArray[i].value;
    arr2[i] = combinedArray[i].arr2Value;
  }
}

const arr1 = [4, 2, 3, 5, 1];
const arr2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];

customSort(arr1, arr2);

console.log('Sorted arr1:', JSON.stringify(arr1));
console.log('Corresponding arr2:', JSON.stringify(arr2));
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're attempting to sort items using a representation function. The items are in the form of entries `[i, value]`, and the representation function `repr(item)` allows to organize the items based on their initial component, `i`.
The `TrueSet` from the [@ut8pia/classifier](https://github.com/ut8pia/classifier) library is specifically designed for such a purpose.

```
import {TrueSet} from "@ut8pia/classifier/queue/TrueSet.js";
import assert from "assert";

const 
    data = [[4, 'a'], [2, 'b'], [3, 'c'], [5, 'd'], [1, 'e']],
    expected = [[1, 'e'], [2, 'b'], [3, 'c'], [4, 'a'], [5, 'd']]
```

All you need to do is add your items to the `TrueSet`:

```
const got = new TrueSet(([i, value]) => i)
    .letAll(data);

assert.deepEqual(got.toArray(), expected)
```